# Exporting Google Apps Scripts Project with C# using REST API v3

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to download the **.gs** and **.html** files from a Google Apps Scripts project; however, it's proving to be a difficult task due to poor documentation.

I'm currently utilizing the Drive Rest v3 API.

The error I keep getting is:

> The service drive has thrown an exception:
>
> ```
> Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> The requested conversion is not supported. [400]
> Errors [
>         Message[The requested conversion is not supported.] Location[convertTo - parameter] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
> ]
>    at Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader.d__31.MoveNext() in C:\Apiary\2018-05-30.11-21-16\Src\Support\Google.Apis\Download\MediaDownloader.cs:line 323
> Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader+DownloadProgress
> ```

I have a feeling that the MIME type might be off. Here's the code.

```
DriveService ds = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
 ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

FilesResource.ExportRequest exp = ds.Files.Export(id,"application/vnd.google-apps.script");

//exp.Alt = DriveBaseServiceRequest<string>.AltEnum.Json;
//FilesResource.GetRequest get = new FilesResource.GetRequest(ds, id);

var streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

exp.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
(IDownloadProgress progress) =>
{
switch (progress.Status)
{
  case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
  {
    Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
    break;
  }
  case DownloadStatus.Completed:
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
    break;
  }
  case DownloadStatus.Failed:
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
    Console.WriteLine(progress.Exception);
    break;
  }
}
};
IDownloadProgress i = exp.DownloadWithStatus(streamer);
```

Comment: Per the API reference, `files.export` is for Google Docs. Review https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: You can download scripts from a project using projects.getContent of Apps Script API. You can see the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent). When you use this API, please be careful the scopes.

Comment: Actually, not quite, but your response led me to dig down that page to find the documentation. Using the same code with the MIME type "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json" allows the apps script to convert to JSON properly. The next challenge is parsing the JSON content into specific files. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Google launched [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) in 2017, an official tool to import and export apps scripts projects and develop locally. 
That is the recomended way to download the .gs and .html files from a Google Apps Scripts project. 
Try the **clasp pull** commmand, it works great!